# How to put a string fith first r characters bold in ListBox Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I tried to put a string in ListBox in Tkinter using ANSI escape sequence "\033[1m" before, and using ANSI escape sequence "\033[0m" after .

```
l = Listbox(root, width=33,font = ('Arial', 15))
a="aaaabc"
l.insert(END,"\033[1m" + a[0:r] + "\033[0m"+a[r:]")
```

What I got is

```
SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash
```

Comment: Do you need this? -> `l.insert(END, f"\033[1m{a[0:r]}\033[0m{a[r:]}")`

Comment: Obviously don't, but you can only setup font for entire ListBox, so I don't know how to bold just some characters

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ANSI escape sequences in the listbox, nor is there any way to change the attributes of only some characters in an item.

If you need to have rich formatting, you will need to use a widget that supports rich formatting. The only practical choice is a `Text` widget, which means you'll have to supply your own bindings to make it behave like a listbox.